# Horror movie that takes place in a hospital, includes time manipulation

Tags: horror, identify-this-movie

I watched this move about 5 years ago and I can only remember certain details about the movie:

- I think a bunch of teenage kids sneak into an old abandoned psych ward or maybe hospital.
- There is a scene where a fox is peeing on a wall outside and the fox and clock above freezes to indicate that time is frozen when they enter the building.
- A couple of security guards get shot.
- There is a scene where a girl climbs into a tub and it fills with blood.
- There are creatures with long bird-like masks on.
- Almost everyone dies.

I think it was made after 2000.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [The Sick House](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0451197/combined) from 2008 which takes place in an abandoned hospital:

> In London, the archeologist Anna Ash is informed by her Professor Joan Holland that the excavation site at the Sixteenth Century Ludgate Orphanage, where she is researching the Cult of the Black Priest during the Great Plague, will be demolished on the next morning to contain the contamination since it has been found the Y.pestis in the digging. The stubborn Anna breaks in the building at midnight expecting to find any substantial evidence that could stop the demolition. Meanwhile, four drugged punks hit and run with a stolen car and they hide inside the building.

I think they're stuck in some sort of loop where ghosts make them relive history, a fact they realize **after seeing the same fox peeing under a clock.** Here's the trailer (**WARNING: Graphic**):

Comment: Thank you so much !!!! I have been looking for the name of this movie for years! I appreciate it!

Comment: @user18992 No problem :) but please click on the check mark to mark it as solved.